# How to read Mongodb data to CSV file using Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, csv

Please anyone can help me how to dump all the Mongodb data to CSV file in Java?

I have done like this but for nested data it doesn't works.The purpose for writing to csv file is that i need to export all data to Jtable since all my processing is done on jtable

```
     MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");

    ListCollectionsIterable collections = db.listCollections();

    MongoCursor collectionsCursor = collections.iterator();

    while (collectionsCursor.hasNext()) {
        Document collectionDocument = (Document) collectionsCursor.next();

        String name = collectionDocument.getString("name");
        if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("system.indexes")) {
            MongoCollection collectionTemp = db.getCollection(name);

            boolean collectionFirst = true;
            MongoCursor<Document> cursorDoc = collectionTemp.find().iterator();
            while (cursorDoc.hasNext()) {

                Document collectionElement = cursorDoc.next();
                boolean first = true;
                Set<String> keySet = collectionElement.keySet();
                if (collectionFirst) {
                    for (String key : keySet)
                        if (first) {
                            System.out.print(key);
                            first = !first;
                        } else
                            System.out.print("," + key);

                    collectionFirst = !collectionFirst;
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                first = true;
                for (String key : keySet)
                    if (first) {
                        System.out.print(collectionElement.get(key));
                        first = !first;
                    } else
                    {

                        System.out.print("," + collectionElement.get(key));

                    }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: And mongoexport to csv don't work to you?

Comment: i tried with mongoexport..but in that i need to specify field.For ex-String command = "C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.6\\bin\\mongoexport.exe --host " + Host + " --port "
    + Port + " --db " + db + " --collection " + col + " --type=csv --fields _id,title,createdAt, --out "
    + fileName + ""